# problem sending relative locktime (OP_CSV) transaction

Tags: raw-transaction, bitcoinjs, checksequenceverify

i tried making a relative timelocked transaction with 1 block timelock (spendable after 1 confirmation)

funding tx:
0fda5412da2a2615361914fad007aac73154746108d44c04529e78f6c4424655

address: tb1qkrz7wne7p05fkgpzk8w9w8pzqswp85zcwcckr4s2z02qr03ksp6qmfduak

script:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet decodescript 21020a14f343fa6b145921de84ff593e16007dcceba46550e2175e86cc14a8cf40cbad51b2
{
  "asm": "020a14f343fa6b145921de84ff593e16007dcceba46550e2175e86cc14a8cf40cb OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY 1 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "2NFQbJj3QRhDXEa1TVoA92q5Ssygv7i4kK3",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 b0c5e74f3e0be89b2022b1dc571c22041c13d058763161d60a13d401be368074",
    "hex": "0020b0c5e74f3e0be89b2022b1dc571c22041c13d058763161d60a13d401be368074",
    "address": "tb1qkrz7wne7p05fkgpzk8w9w8pzqswp85zcwcckr4s2z02qr03ksp6qmfduak",
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "p2sh-segwit": "2N8xFW1ta5EhgMtsqRx32DCGwbUrey4rwvN"
  }
}
```

spending tx but it gives an error

```
01000000000101554642c4f6789e52044cd40861745431c7aa07d0fa14193615262ada1254da0f0000000000010000000179030000000000001600140aa46507f4b5c291f40224a8cb62cca18222d56d0247304402203216b9f5518ae00a8d8d16bf7c73376cc77c1f81bece6c3f4daac7f906e7030102201961be0b1464d3637e566765a37da6885e94b91155dbba4373d269840b4125f4012521020a14f343fa6b145921de84ff593e16007dcceba46550e2175e86cc14a8cf40cbad51b200000000
```

my first try also failed with the same error, it was a relative locktime of 5 blocks

address: tb1qmsws55wqcg6glcrk9urnjqfw0mpqp6uralha5y99wf8pvnh3sqjs8cm92l

script:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet decodescript 21020a14f343fa6b145921de84ff593e16007dcceba46550e2175e86cc14a8cf40cbad55b2
{
  "asm": "020a14f343fa6b145921de84ff593e16007dcceba46550e2175e86cc14a8cf40cb OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY 5 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "2MuimPJ2k6SArD9aCchJDdWbVHeyR2cBoUo",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 dc1d0a51c0c2348fe0762f0739012e7ec200eb83efefda10a5724e164ef18025",
    "hex": "0020dc1d0a51c0c2348fe0762f0739012e7ec200eb83efefda10a5724e164ef18025",
    "address": "tb1qmsws55wqcg6glcrk9urnjqfw0mpqp6uralha5y99wf8pvnh3sqjs8cm92l",
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "p2sh-segwit": "2N1iz6k1KgHRsYNWT64HF2fcCQduJ22DYfH"
  }
}
```

tx:

```
0100000000010171ea228f6f77c4a4fc427ca35cb09889d61673671d7321c07a2ceb5b653d62d90000000000010000000179030000000000001600140aa46507f4b5c291f40224a8cb62cca18222d56d02483045022100f33f68f8b67ab722ea82a125287bfd3d9cfd920df8a41d6286790e4fe65afe770220780cbc8b3b8d44fcc08237e7133c86d1a73b2d55cd3dadc0d850416fdd7e0164012521020a14f343fa6b145921de84ff593e16007dcceba46550e2175e86cc14a8cf40cbad55b200000000
```

error:

```
(-26)  non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Locktime requirement not satisfied)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY` is only available for transactions with their version number set to 2. Your transactions have a version number of 1, and so they fail.

Comment: thanks, after setting the version to 2 and signing them again they both went through.